# How do I make a custom override of Joomlas JHtmlTabs?

Tags: php, joomla

I am attempting to make a simple override to the `JHtmlTabs` function without editing the core files.

I've tried making a copy of the tabs file (found in `/library/html/html/tabs.php`), and modifying it to simply extend the original file, but any modification I make either results in the page crashing with `Fatal error: Class 'JHtmlTabs' not found` or my modifications don't appear.

Is there a specific way to handle overriding this?

Comment: Please check: [Joomla Override](http://community.joomla.org/blogs/community/521-did-you-know-overrides-are-not-just-for-html.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the class into memory.  The error is the result of your extending a class it can't find.  At the top of the class file extending the JHtmlTabs class add this line:

```
JLoader::register('JHtmlTabs', JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries/joomla/html/tabs.php');
```

This should load the class into memory and remove your error.

Comment: No dice, I added the JLoader right before the class is defined, and I continue to get the same error.

Comment: Here's an exact copy of the file: http://codepad.org/6aITV4gP
Haven't made any major changes to it compared to the Joomla base, but this was more of an opening to try to test to see if I could modify.

Comment: Any particular reason your custom class is abstract?  Although it can technically be done, it serves no functional purpose I'm aware of.  Also, one of the primary benefits of inheritance is to extend existing functionality, ergo; there's no need for you to have any of the parent class JHtmlTabs methods in your class unless you are overriding them.

Comment: The function is abstract simply because the original Joomla function was abstract and I was working under the assumption that that would affect my ability to override some of the functions. Also, I am trying to override some of their methods to outright control the output of the tabs (mostly trying to replace the ridiculous `<span><h3></h3></span>` tags around the tab title and use something more flexible.

Comment: Makes sense, you don't need to make your class abstract and you only need to include the methods in your class you plan on overriding.  That, however, will not done the issue of the class but being found.  Can you confirm the file for the patent class is actually there?  Maybe you inadvertantly did a cut instead of a copy?

Comment: Actually, never mind, I see the problem.  I made a typo in my answer which I just corrected.  The path to for the JHtmlTabs class was wrong, I edited/corrected my post.  Add the corrected path and everything should work.

Comment: Well, fortunately your correction to `JLoader` worked in removing the errors. However, my overrides for the functions don't seem to be working. I stripped the file of the functions I don't need and removed the abstract bit. The file is now simply http://codepad.org/50TdM2CP. I thought it might have been an issue when I called `jimport( 'joomla.html.html.tabs' );` inside the file using the tabs, but no luck.

Comment: can you post the code where you instantiate you custom JHtmlTabs class and render the tab content?

Comment: Here's a copy of the php document calling the tabs. Obviously abbreviated code to reduce the amount of unneeded information and to not spread out company code. http://codepad.org/UqtGZdf7

Comment: With the code you pasted the core JHtmlTabs will be used to render the layout every time.  The reason being is you are using Joomla's core JHtml utility class, which is an entry point for many, many, many features.  If you want to use your custom class, you will need to forgoe using the JHtml helper class, include your custom class using require_once or JLoader::register and manually call the required methods to build out your tabs.  I have to be honest though, you might be better served creating a custom layout file for your component or template.